OAuth2 + ADFS + client credentials
We are configuring OAuth2 client credentials authorization flow using ADFS as the Identity Provider to authorize a service to service interaction (exactly what client credentials is designed for).
We have an Active Directory user account that is a member of groups, and we are using those groups as a source of authorization claims in the access token.
We configured the other flows, and when we use the "password" flow for example, we get user groups in "roles" claim inside the access token.
When we use the client credentials flow, we don't receive any claims related to the roles. We suspect this is because of the lack of relation between the client id and that user account in AD. We've tried to relate one with the other by setting:

Server application client properties -> confidential -> AD user principal name

to the domain\user of the related technical user, but this doesn't change anything.
Is this the correct way to go about this, are we missing something or are we doing it completely wrong?

Client credentials are designed to be used in backend server/daemon type applications, so there is no context of a user.
It uses the context of the application.

I understand this, but I still would expect to get some authorities/roles with the token, otherwise the token seems useless for the authorization purposes.

Access tokens are more around scopes/permissions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scopes-oidc

Yes, and that's what I would like to get. Authorities/permissions/scopes are used interchangably in this context. Maybe we are doing it wrong by trying to relate an AD user with a given client id (although there is this field that I mentioned in adfs), maybe there's another method of assigning scopes/permissions/authorities/roles to a client id than by specyfing a user that's as the source of those.
